# regex replace <br /> between <p> and </p>

Tags: php, regex

I have a string of html with consists of many `<p>` tags and other html tags.

How can I replace `<br />` tags between `<p>` and `</p>` tag, so that it become multiple paragraphs using regex?

(I need to replace in `<p>` tag only, not in other tags)

Sample source:

```
<p> This is a paragraph without line break</p>
<p> This is a paragraph with <br /> line <br /> break</p>
```

Sample output:

```
<p> This is a paragraph without line break</p>
<p> This is a paragraph with </p><p> line </p><p> break</p>
```

Comment: Would you like to write regexp with php? Or in any other language?

Comment: Suggest to use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) instead of preg_replace function. Or You need to replace <br /> only inside <p></p>?

Comment: From your question it seems that you don't want to replace the `<br />` if it is not between `<p>` tags - but your sample doesn't cover that.

Comment: Sorry, I need to replace <br />only inside <p> </p> only, not in other tags. Forgot to mention inside question.

Comment: "using regex" — Why do you have this requirement? [Regular expressions are not well suited to manipulating HTML. There are better ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/19068).

Comment: If not using regex, any better suggestion? sorry I'm still not that familiar with php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$string = '<p> This is a paragraph without line break</p>
text <br /> without p <br />
<p> This is a paragraph with <br /> line <br /> break</p>
<p>aaaa <br /></p>
dsa<br />
<p><br /></p>';

// Start non-greedy search for text in paragraphs
preg_match_all('/<p>.*?<\/p>/im', $string, $matches);

$matches = $matches[0];

// for each match replace <br /> inside text
foreach ($matches as $key => $match) {
    $replaced[$key]['initial'] = $match;
    $replaced[$key]['replaced'] = str_replace('<br />', '</p><p>', $match);
}

// replacing initial parts of text with replaced parts
foreach ($replaced as $key => $replacePair) {
    $string = str_replace($replacePair['initial'], $replacePair['replaced'], $string);
}

print_r ($string);
```

[sandbox code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/054bec81bf2d56d7fec203315e4b99950df79d27)

Answer (score -1):

Use PHP function str_replace. It'll replace all "br" tags. Use it like this:

```
$result = str_replace('<br />', '', $input);
```

Comment: use this. dont use regex with html, it's not healthy or fun. See here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: This doesn't meet the "Only inside p elements" restriction that the question imposes. This doesn't meet the requirement to turn line breaks into paragraph breaks that the question imposes.  It is also very fragile and depends on the very specific Appendix C form of the br element.